# How to animate and update the title,xlabel,ylabel?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib. Based on my code in following, I wanted to update the data,title,xlabel,ylabel at same time. However, the title and labels did not been updated, but data did.Someone can give me a solution? That will help me a lot.Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def updata(frame_number):
    current_index = frame_number % 3
    a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    idata['position'][:,0] = np.asarray(a[current_index])
    idata['position'][:,1] = np.asarray(a[current_index])
    scat.set_offsets(idata['position'])
    ax.set_xlabel('The Intensity of Image1')
    ax.set_ylabel('The Intensity of Image2')
    ax.set_title("For Dataset %d" % current_index)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
idata = np.zeros(3,dtype=[('position',float,2)])
ax.set_title(label='lets begin',fontdict = {'fontsize':12},loc='center')
scat = ax.scatter(idata['position'][:,0],idata['position'][:,1],s=10,alpha=0.3,edgecolors='none')
animation = FuncAnimation(fig,updata,interval=2000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code you show already updates the labels and the title. It is therefore unclear what you want to achieve. Please read [ask] and provide a clear problem description (what do you want to achieve, what have you tried, in how far does it not give the desired result?).

Comment: If you run the code, I think  you can find that the labels and the title would not be updated. Thanks for your advice, I will edit my problem base on your comment. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 3):

Running the code, I see an empty window. The reason is that the axes span the complete figure (`fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`). In order to see the title and labels, you would need to make the axes smaller than the figure, e.g. by

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Also, the scale of the axes is not defined, so the animation will happen outside the axes limits. You can use `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim` to prevent that.

Here is a complete running code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def updata(frame_number):
    current_index = frame_number % 3
    a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    idata['position'][:,0] = np.asarray(a[current_index])
    idata['position'][:,1] = np.asarray(a[current_index])
    scat.set_offsets(idata['position'])
    ax.set_xlabel('The Intensity of Image1')
    ax.set_ylabel('The Intensity of Image2')
    ax.set_title("For Dataset %d" % current_index)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
idata = np.zeros(3,dtype=[('position',float,2)])
ax.set_title(label='lets begin',fontdict = {'fontsize':12},loc='center')
scat = ax.scatter(idata['position'][:,0],idata['position'][:,1],
                  s=25,alpha=0.9,edgecolors='none')
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
animation = FuncAnimation(fig,updata,frames=50,interval=600)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome!!!Thanks Very Much. I spent much time in looking for the documents, just tried to solve the problem. But I got nothing in the matplotlib website and I think it's not friendly for the beginner. Just my personal opinion. Again, Thanks for your solutions.