# Matplotlib animation update suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to show in an animated plot bunches of images (which I assign to specific subplots). To this reason I wrote the following (I am using a jupyter notebook):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

img1 = np.random.rand(1, 4)
img2 = np.random.rand(2, 4)
img3 = np.random.rand(3, 4)
img4 = np.random.rand(4, 4)
images = [[img1, img2], [img3, img4]]

%matplotlib auto #The only way I found so that this does not show an extra chart
def gen_anim():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ims = []
    for i in range(2):
        im_1 = ax.ravel()[0].imshow(images[i][0], animated = True)
        ax.ravel()[0].axis('off')
        im_2 = ax.ravel()[1].imshow(images[i][1], animated = True)
        ax.ravel()[1].axis('off')
        ims.append([im_1, im_2])
        plt.suptitle(t = 'Image set' + str(i), fontsize = 20)
    return fig, ims

fig, ims = gen_anim()
rc('animation', html='html5')
anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=1000, blit = True, repeat_delay = 1000)
anim
```

This works great except for the fact that I cannot update the suptitle of each set of images. I have seen examples where the title of each of the charts gets updated ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385784/how-to-animate-and-update-the-title-xlabel-ylabel)) but (based on my limited understanding of matplotlib) the suptitle is not the same.

So my question would be: Is it possible to update the suptitle in the current setting or should I try my luck with `FuncAnimation`?

(My efforts with `FuncAnimation` so far have been disappointing)

```
def animate(i):
    to_plot_imgs = images[i]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)    
    for j in range(2):
        ax.ravel()[j].imshow(to_plot_imgs[j], interpolation='bilinear', animated = True)
        ax.ravel()[j].axis('off')            
    plt.suptitle(t = 'Image set' + str(i), fontsize = 20)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=len(images), interval=500)
anim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title can also be changed dynamically by using the Funcanimation function. Initially, we set no title and font size, and update it with set_text during the animation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np

img1 = np.random.rand(1, 4)
img2 = np.random.rand(2, 4)
img3 = np.random.rand(3, 4)
img4 = np.random.rand(4, 4)
images = [[img1, img2], [img3, img4]]
# %matplotlib auto #The only way I found so that this does not show an extra chart

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
title = plt.suptitle(t='', fontsize = 20)

def animate(i):
    to_plot_imgs = images[i]
#     fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)    
    for j in range(2):
        ax.ravel()[j].imshow(to_plot_imgs[j], interpolation='bilinear', animated = True)
        ax.ravel()[j].axis('off')
        title.set_text('Image set{}'.format(i))

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(images), interval=1500, repeat=False)

plt.close()
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! May I ask some clarification for the logic? As in how does the text get assigned to the title (matplotlib noob, so it all seems like magic to me :))

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, I first set the initial title as empty. The animation function updates the text of the title initially set by the 'i' variable.